# Glide dont load image from document

Tags: android-studio, imageview, uri, android-glide

i have external local database and i have to save image into database,
image come from camera and gallery and image drawable
glide load image from imagedrawble but cant load image from camera or gallery 
and i save uri these images

glide can load this uri from image drawable

```
  content://media/external/images/media/772718
```

but cant load this uri from camera or gallery

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A772711
```

i load image this way

```
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(modelInsertInfo.getImage_src());

    Log.d("LOG30",uri.toString());
    Glide.with(this).load(uri).into(imgDetail);
```

Comment: Find file path from your `Uri` and pass it to your **Glide source** when loading image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try obtaining path from your **`uri`** object and pass it to **Glide**, check the code below :

```
Glide.with(this).load(uri.getPath()).into(imgDetail); // get path from Uri and pass it to glide.
```